# Get string between two strings repeatable in C#

Tags: c#

I saw this topic many times like

> Get string between two strings

But i didnt found how can i get string between two string in whole text like
For example i have text

key1

random text here

another random text

key2

here random text

here random text

here random text

key1

some text again

key2

So i want program to get text between **key1** and **key2** so for the output should look like

> random text her
>
> another random text
>
> some text again
> I used following method

```
 public static string GetStringBetween(this string token, string first, string second)
        {
            if (!token.Contains(first)) return "";

            var afterFirst = token.Split(new[] { first }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

            if (!afterFirst.Contains(second)) return "";

            var result = afterFirst.Split(new[] { second }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];

            return result;
        }
```

But it gets only first text from key1 and key2 above. So i want program to get for each key1 and key2 text between this two words (key1 and key2).

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Then you need to organize a loop to continue search after first match was found.

Comment: @Sinatr no, this is not working

Answer (score 1):

Found answer.Exact what i want. Thanks for everyone who support me!!!

```
   private static List<string> ExtractFromBody(string body, string start, string end)
            {
                List<string> matched = new List<string>();
        
                int indexStart = 0;
                int indexEnd = 0;
        
                bool exit = false;
                while (!exit)
                {
                    indexStart = body.IndexOf(start);
        
                    if (indexStart != -1)
                    {
                        indexEnd = indexStart + body.Substring(indexStart).IndexOf(end);
        
                        matched.Add(body.Substring(indexStart + start.Length, indexEnd - indexStart - start.Length));
        
                        body = body.Substring(indexEnd + end.Length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        exit = true;
                    }
                }
        
                return matched;
            }
```